# How to use the SqlProvider tables in an existing (Entity-Framework) database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

Is it possible to create an **EF** connection string with both my tables and **SqlProvider** tables, so that I can do something along the lines of:

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(
    "username", "password",
    "email", "question ",
    "answer", true, out status
);
```

where it will add a new user in the tables that the **SqlProvider** created.

I am geting a **"Keyword not supported: 'metadata'"** exception thrown because SQLProvider requires an ADO connection string, but I have to get my tables using the EF connection string.

As far as I know you can not combine **code-first** and **database-first** approaches in the same project so I'm in a dilemma as to how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Can you add the connection strings to the question?

Comment: Right now I have just one EF connection string and he contains both my tables and SqlProvider tables: 

<add name="DBEntitiesConnString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DB.csdl|res://*/Models.DB.ssdl|res://*/Models.DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=top-developing.ddns.net,1434;initial catalog=****;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=*****;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: And for your code first are you using SqlDbContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. However, you probably don't need to, if you use the same database for the AspNet identity and your own tables.

In that case, you can just import all your AspNet identity tables into your edmx, and use them as any other entity. You can also create PK-FK relationships in the database between your tables and identity tables, which means that you can query users from the dbcontext, get theirs related entities etc.

So, in that case, the identity will use its connection string and the rest of the application will use yours.

You just have to be careful to change both connection strings if your database changes.